# How to place equations that start with left alignment?

Tags: equations

when we write equation, all equations do not start from same (left) alignment?
Is it possible to like that?

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
GDS_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 {EGPI\_A}_t+\beta_2 {NGPI\_A}_t+\beta_3Y_t+\beta_4 GDS_{t-1}+\epsilon_t                       
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
GDS_t=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 {GPI\_A}_t+\alpha_2 Y_t+\epsilon_t
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:3}
GDS_t=\delta_0+\delta_1 {EGPI\_UA}_t+\delta_2 {NGPI\_UA}_t+\delta_3Y_t+\delta_4 GDS_{t-1}+\epsilon_t
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:4}
GDS_t=\gamma_0+\gamma_1 {GPI\_UA}_t+\gamma_2 Y_t+\gamma_3 GDS_{t-1}+\epsilon_t
\end{equation}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Add a MWE. It is messy what you wrote.

Comment: Might be an idea to learn to use `amsmath` and its `align` env, it does exactly what you want.

Comment: @daleif, i am using amsmth package. But it does not create equations as i want. I tried with align env. Any help regarding how to use align? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `fleqn` document option.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
GDS_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 {EGPI\_A}_t+\beta_2 {NGPI\_A}_t+\beta_3Y_t+\beta_4 GDS_{t-1}+\epsilon_t                       
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
GDS_t=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 {GPI\_A}_t+\alpha_2 Y_t+\epsilon_t
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:3}
GDS_t=\delta_0+\delta_1 {EGPI\_UA}_t+\delta_2 {NGPI\_UA}_t+\delta_3Y_t+\delta_4 GDS_{t-1}+\epsilon_t
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:4}
GDS_t=\gamma_0+\gamma_1 {GPI\_UA}_t+\gamma_2 Y_t+\gamma_3 GDS_{t-1}+\epsilon_t
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I would however suggest to use `align` and typeset multiletter identifiers using `\mathrm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\GDS{\mathrm{GDS}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \label{eq:1}
  \GDS_t&=\beta_0+\beta_1 \mathrm{EGPI\_A}_t+\beta_2 \mathrm{NGPI\_A}_t+\beta_3Y_t+\beta_4 \GDS_{t-1}+\epsilon_t \\
  \label{eq:2}
  \GDS_t&=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 \mathrm{GPI\_A}_t+\alpha_2 Y_t+\epsilon_t \\
  \label{eq:3}
  \GDS_t&=\delta_0+\delta_1 \mathrm{EGPI\_UA}_t+\delta_2 \mathrm{NGPI\_UA}_t+\delta_3Y_t+\delta_4 \GDS_{t-1}+\epsilon_t \\
  \label{eq:4}
  \GDS_t&=\gamma_0+\gamma_1 \mathrm{GPI\_UA}_t+\gamma_2 Y_t+\gamma_3 \GDS_{t-1}+\epsilon_t
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]